# How do I use .NET MVC3 to generate a view model that addresses one-to-many relationships?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, linq-to-entities

### Technical Details

C#, ASP.NET 4, MVC 3, SQL backend, ADO.NET (edmx)

### Background/Context

I have been using MVC for a few years now and know how to effectively use the pattern in .NET; however, I have never used .NET's native view model generation (i.e. "Create new Controller" with scaffolding and auto-generated CRUD views).

Generally, I like to create POCO's on my own, package them following my own model patterns, and then create the views on my own.  Today, however, I have a need to rapidly prototype something and I am leaning on .NET's automation/templates to help me get things done quickly.

I have generated this entity model:
[image]

From this, I am able to auto generate simple controllers and forms.

### The Problem

Please take a look at the "flow_product" entity.  You will notice that it has a one-to-many relationship with the "optionGroup" entity.  Therefore, I would expect to have a check box list generated with the "Edit/Create" view models to handle this association.  Instead, all I see when I let .NET handle the generation of the view are fields for `name` and `description`.

Am I missing something here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new t4 templates for making edit and detail pages etc. for your strongly typed classes and make them available in the create view wizard by dropping them in a folder in your vs2010 folder under your profile but nothing comes OoTB like you described.

if you're just mocking up a prototype you could look at the dynamic data website project. Not sure if it's still in 2010 though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that MVC has auto-scaffolding for lists like that.  It's a pretty simple matter of putting in a loop and a checkbox however.

Comment: Thanks.  I know how to do it manually, just wondering if I can auto-gen.

Comment: I figured you did. Like I said, I don't know that auto-gen exists.